# how to show and hide div using two different link

Tags: html

I am having HTML page where i ll have link as "SHOW" while clicking on that I need to show div area.  where DIV has iframe.

Normally while loading HTML page that div should be in hidden state while clicking only it should be shown.

I need close button inside that link..While clicking on that I need to close the dive that is hide.

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggleDisplay('toHide')">a</a>
function toggleDisplay(id)
    {
       if (!document.getElementById) {  return; }
       var el = document.getElementById('straddle');
       if (el.style.display == ''){
          el.style.display = 'none';
       }else {
          el.style.display = '';
       }
    }
```

I don't want this toggle function

Please help me.

Comment: `if (!document.getElementById)` seems to be wrong

Comment: 1)if (!document.getElementById) which ID are u looking for?
2)whats display:''?? If i know correctly, if you want your div to be visible, you set it to display:block/inline/inline-block.
3)And you want a close button inside the div??

Comment: But I need two different link to show and hide..
Show button in HTML page 
Hide button inside DIV

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var whatever = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    whatever.style.display = 'none';

    function show(){
          whatever.style.display = 'block';   
    }

    function hide(){
          whatever.style.display = 'none';
         }
//-->
</script>
```

and then the HTML

```
    <a href="#" onclick="show();">Click here to show element </a>
<br/>
<div id="mydiv">
This will disappear and reappear and 
<a href="#" onclick="hide();">Click here remove element</a></div>`
```

Comment: But I need two different link to show and hide..
Show button in HTML page 
Hide button inside DIV

Comment: @user3007361 just edited it for you, now should work as u want it

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link1').click(function() { $('#div').css({ display:'none' }) })
    $('#link2').click(function() { $('#div').css({ display:'block' }) })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QmJT5/2/) (`Iframe` may take a while to load, so let it load)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="show">Show</a>
<div id="straddle">
    <div id="close">Close</div>
    <iframe width='100%' src="http://heera.it"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JS:** (Put it before closong `</body>` tag between `<scripe type="text/javascript"></scripe>`)

```
window.onload = function() {
    var show = document.getElementById('show'),
        el = document.getElementById('straddle'),
        close = document.getElementById('close');
    show.onclick = function() {
        el.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    };
    close.onclick = function(){
        el.style.display = 'none';
    };
};
```

**Update :** Added relevant `css`

```css
#straddle{ display:none; }
#close{
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi.1st time while opening HTML page..DIV should be hidden..onlu=y on clicking show i need to show Div

Comment: @user3007361, Yes, it's hidden at first time, check the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/QmJT5/2/), add the `css`.

Comment: Thank you..In my HTML page i ll show some data..Once clicking my div should be above that data..Inner that HTML